# "Failed to obtain a cell" error trying to use a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, syntax-error, swift3

I'm trying to return the number of rows in a table using the following code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let count = FirstTableArray.count
    print(count)//prints 5
    return count
}
```

It won't work giving the following error

> 2016-11-20 13:28:46.787 ModularProject[10870:2357799] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.5.2/UITableView.m:8035
>   2016-11-20 13:28:46.829 ModularProject[10870:2357799] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {375, 44}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource ()'

I can't work out why, forcing 0 as the return variable works but not 1???

Edit 1:

Here is my cellForRowAt method for reference

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("runs")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    print("runs2")
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Foo"
    return cell
    print("runs3")
}
```

Comment: Did you implement cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Yes I did afterwards

Comment: What happened after you implement it?

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with the `numberOfRowsInSection` method. Your error is caused by your `cellForRowAt` method. Please update your question with that method.

Comment: BTW - always [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+failed+to+obtain+a+cell+from+its+dataSource) before posting. I'm sure you'll find your solution with one of those previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing 0 works because then the tableView thinks it has no rows to show, therefore it does not try to call the `cellForRowAt` method.

Therefore, if you want to use any number 1 or greater, you have to implement `cellForRowAt`, which is required by the `UITableViewDataSource`.  Here's an example:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Foo"
    return cell
}
```

Assuming you're using the storyboard, make sure you set your cell identifier here in the code, which I've used in the example as "Cell", to match whatever you're using as the cell identifier in your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether you are getting cell as nil in

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
}
```

if object return nil

```
let object = line. If the problem is that tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:) // check object here, if nil then
```

If you're using modern Xcode templates where you get a prototype cell made for you, you should probably be using this instead:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
```

If you aren't using an Xcode template, use that line of code anyway then register your own re-use identifier like this:

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

All being well that should resolve the problem. If not, check that the cell identifier is correct: it's "Cell" by default, but you might have changed it. Such a misspelling ought to cause a crash when `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` fails, but it's worth checking anyway.

Let me know if this work for you.

Comment: Hey, I understand your comments but it still doesn't seem to work. The identifier cell is correct in the storyboard and the code you use is the exam same as mine, (see main problem edit). It prints runs but not runs2 showing the error is with the "dequeueReusableIdentifier" line

Answer (score -1):

you check your delegate and DataSource?

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableVie.dataSource = self
```

Not sure if you know but you have to put the Protocols in your class?

```
class MyClass: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {}
```

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the error in the question. If the data source isn't set, the table will simply show no rows. There won't be any errors. If the protocols are not set on the `class` line, then the code wouldn't compile when trying to set the `dataSource` and `delegate` properties.

Comment: @rmaddy If you directly set the `dataSource` and `delegate` from the storyboard **and** don't conform the class to the protocols, the code will compile and cause the crash OP is facing. Not sure if thats what the answer writer meant though.